# Can you suggest Youtube style video service that uses Silverlight?

Tags: video, silverlight

Can anyone suggest a service similar to youtube that uses Silverlight for the player. I need embedding support and I need a free or cheap service.

To answer the inevitable question - I don't want to use a Flash based service because I am going to upload .NET related tech presentation (in Bulgarian). I'm going for a *practice what you preach* approach and want to avoid mocking the community.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has their own site as an expo of what Silverlight can do called Channel9:
http://channel9.msdn.com/

Its a nice example, but the content is controlled by Microsoft it seems...
For an end-user site that allows uploads, try:
http://bcmoney-mobiletv.com/view/1606/scotty-and-the-stars-live/

(A little shameless self-promotion, but my site supports WMV streaming, that is one example. Although, I have not added this support officially into the upload process, so if you wanted to use it I'd suggest to upload first as WMV... video hosting is the expensive part, so if you want me to share the formula I can explain how to do that on your own site as well)